# unable to check the query by if statement

Tags: php

I want to check if the path of the image is NULL or not but the if statement after my select query as shown below doesn't work; the code directly passes to else statement and displays the div in else statement, so anyone who can help me please...

```
<div class="adminLeft">
<?php 
$userID=$_SESSION['userID'];
$sql="SELECT path from cim WHERE userID='$userID'";
$res=mysql_query($sql);
if ($res==NULL)
{
?>
<div class="card">
<p> <img class ="card-img-top" src="/images/picture-profile.jpg"></p> 
</p>    
</div>
<br>
<form id="uploadprofpic" action="up.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" 
method="post">
<p> <input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*"></p>
<input name="submit" class="formbutton" value="Upload your Photo" 
type="submit" id="submitReport"/>
</form>
<?php }
else {?>
<div class="card">
<p> <img class ="card-img-top" src=""></p> 
}
?> </p>
</div>
```

Comment: you're open to SQL injection and should resolve imminently - also where's your `session_start()` function? double also - `mysql_*` functions were deprecated in php5 and removed in php7 - update your code to use `mysqli_*` functions or my pref. PDO

Comment: `"NULL"` and `NULL` are not the same thing. One is a string, and the other is null.

Answer (score 1):

You are checking for a string "NULL", changing it to just `NULL` will check if it returned `NULL`

```
<?php 
if ($res == NULL){
?>
<div class="card">       
<p> <img class ="card-img-top" src="/images/picture-profile.jpg"></p> 
<?php }?>         
</div>
```

So now if it returns `NULL` it will show the div.

**By the way you are not closing the php properly in the end, you have `>?` it is supposed to be `?>`**

Comment: Mind to explain the -1? Since I tested it and it works on my end.

Comment: It doesn't work; it directly passes to else statement even if the query result is null.

Comment: Well then there is data in $res so it goes to the else. If you want the div to show when there **is** data you need to change the if to `if($res != NULL){`

Comment: please see my edited question and try to help me thank you!

Comment: Well first of all, you still have `"NULL"` instead of `NULL` that is wrong. I don't know if you know what the if is doing since it is working like it is supposed to, **your if will show the profile picture if there is no path, that is how your code is made** If you don't want that check my other comment.

Comment: no it is NULL key word see it again but it doesn't work still it runs only the else statement by default my assumption is if the path is null the page must allow to upload a photo other wise the upload photo form mus be hidden

Comment: What if you change `if($row == NULL)` to `if (mysql_num_rows($res)==0)`. Because you are probably not saving it with a default of NULL in the databsae so it won't find null, and in that case it will go to the else immediatly.

Comment: I have changed my if statement to if (mysql_num_rows($res)==0) but there is nothing changed.

Comment: Well then the query is finding something in the database

Comment: You also need to open php again before the last } in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try is_null function like this :

```
if (is_null($res)){}
```

Answer (score -1):

use simply `null` not `"NULL"`

```
if ($res==null){
}
```